# iPhone : general debugging tips

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I been doing iPhone development for 8 months or so and general life is good (exception is openGL lol).

I building a iPhone 3D game and things were going well.  It works fine on the simulator (I know not a true test) and it was working fine on the device.

Now it seems to die on the device and point to some very random things.  First time it dies (“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”) is the setting of the delegate.

```
NSString *url = [NSString
stringWithFormat:@"%@GetPlayerPosition.aspx?playerIndex=%@",
self.baseURL, self.deviceID];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];    
[request setDelegate:self];
```

So I just remove the code.

The next time it dies is when it tries to access a GLFloat array

> GLfloat v[] = {center[0] - eye[0],
>   center[1] - eye[1], center[2] -
>   eye[2]};

Again very random and has worked until now.  Its like its running out of memory and just fulls over.  Does anyone have any idea's? is there a limit to a class size?

Generally I would be able to solve this but I even gone back to a working version and reimplemented some code and its then starts random behavior.

I checked for leaks and I am fine

UPDATE: Part 2

Right in my interface in my .h file I have

```
GLfloat eye[3];
```

In my .m, I can assign a value to each element and it works fine

If I do

```
NSLog(@"%f",eye[0]);
```

It crashes.  Why is this? (used to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are center and eye declared?  Are they instance variables, globals or static variables?  It could be somehow the memory for those arrays has been released by the time the callback occurs (which would also explain why the line initializing the float array fails).

Comment: They are declared in the interface (.h)
GLfloat center[3];
GLfloat eye[3];

Comment: Are they class instance variables?  If so, perhaps the class has been released - normally anything used by a block gets retained, but since these are primitive types I'm pretty sure they would not cause a class holding them to be retained.  One technique that might help is to keep the ASIHTTPRequst object you are creating as a class instance variable, and make sure to cancel the request in dealloc of the class.

Comment: So as said they are just declared in the public interface.  Even if I take the blocks out completely it dies on the primitive later on

Comment: I added NSLog(@"%f",eye[0]); and it crashes on accessing this even though via the debugger the float is populated

Comment: Where in the interface file.  If it's between @interface/@end, it's a class instance variable.  If it's outside the @interface block, it's a global variable.  Try NSLog(@"%f %@",eye[0], self); and see if the crash goes away (because it would cause self to be retained).

Comment: Move center and eye outside of the @interface block in the header, up by the imports, and see if it still crashes (if you use more than one instance of the class that might have it freak out since all instances will be using the same array)

Answer (score 2):

- If there is a crash (or crashes), there will be backtraces. Post them.
- Try "build and analyze".  Fix any warnings it gives you.  Fix any warnings the compiler gives you, too.  A properly written app should compile without warnings.
- why the `__block` on that line of code?  There doesn't seem to be anything blocks related there.

Nothing ever randomly breaks when writing software.  If something starts crashing with a seemingly unrelated change, it is likely that the code was always broken, but wasn't causing a fatal problem until the later change.

---

Since you aren't writing to `request`, there is no reason to mark that variable as `__block`.    Since `__block` will cause `request` to *not* be retained, it might be that the object is being prematurely released & deallocated.  Maybe.

How are you allocating the float arrays?

Comment: No warnings or leaks found.  sure its something to do with the float arrays

Comment: I think I marked these as blocks so I could use the completion method. I taken out the blocks and whole request objects. however the normal code still crashes at the NSLog(@"%f",eye[0]); even though eye[] is populated.

Comment: Blocks are fine. `__block` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is often the symptom of premature deallocation (e.g. trying to access a deallocated object because it was released too many times).

> it was working fine [...] Now it seems to die

Sounds like you should look through your revision logs to see what changed between those two timestamps.

Comment: the center[3] and eye[3] should not be released, I have not set them up as a property cause I don't think you can.